# set month, day year the same format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

when I extracted the date column from dataframe it looks like this:

```
10/30/2016

10/30/2016

10/30/2016

10/30/2016

9/4/2017 1

9/4/2017 1

9/4/2017 1

9/4/2017 1

9/4/2017 1
```

I need to set the dates with the same digits format to get rid of the extra 1 from the right.
the format should be :

```
09/04/2017
```

Any help.

Comment: Could you show what has already failed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the following with a regex capture

```
import re
import datetime 
bad_date = "9/4/2017 1"
new_date = re.sub("(\d{,2}/\d{,2}/\d{,4})(\s.*\d+)","\\1", bad_date)
```

Finally with `datetime`

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(new_date, "%d/%m/%Y"))

2017-04-09 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
         date
0  10/30/2016
1  10/30/2016
2  10/30/2016
3  10/30/2016
4  9/4/2017 1
5  9/4/2017 1
6  9/4/2017 1
7  9/4/2017 1
8  9/4/2017 1
```

Doing:

- Simplifying your problem to a string method, `rstrip(' 1')`

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date.str.rstrip(' 1')).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         date
0  10/30/2016
1  10/30/2016
2  10/30/2016
3  10/30/2016
4  09/04/2017
5  09/04/2017
6  09/04/2017
7  09/04/2017
8  09/04/2017
```

---

Or, without ever acknowledging it's a date:

```
df.date = (df.date.str.rstrip(' 1')
                  .str.split('/')
                  .map(lambda row: '/'.join(x.zfill(2) for x in row)))
# Same output as above~
```